# select a1-a100 observations & delete rest observation in sas

Tags: sas

I have a dataset named `b` about various customer named as `a1`,`a2`,`a45`,`a345`,`a999`,`a654`, etc.

I would like to select customer named between `a1`-`a100` and discard others.
I tried this code:

```
data a;
set b;
where customer ne a1-a100;
run;
```

But I am getting this error

> ERROR: Variable a1 is not on file b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the digits in your customer identifier to a number and apply the condition on that number.

```
data a;
    set b;
    if 1 le input(substr(customer,2),8.) le 100;
run;
```

- `substr(customer,2),8.` returns a the 2de till the last character from `customer`, i.e. the digits
- `input(substr(customer,2),8.)` interpretes the digits as a number
- `1 le input(substr(customer,2),8.) le 100` is the sas way to write `input(substr(customer,2),8.) between 1 and 100` *(and it is actually better, as it allows using `lt` in stead of `le` too)*
- `if` without `then` is in this case equivalent to `where`.

Comment: thanks it's work.but i can't understand this code please explain if statement